# Castle Interceptor Life Cycle and Memory Leak

Tags: c#, castle-dynamicproxy

I am new to castle dynamic proxy, and a bit curious..

When creating proxy of my object I save all the original values of its property on the interceptor (class scope) using dictionary and return the new value. Now I am  wondering, when will this data get collected by GC??
Can i control it or does it depend on the interceptor life cycle?

Regards
Kin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interceptor is just an object that the proxy holds reference to. So it will live at least as long as the proxy.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.
anyway thanks for making a great tutorial about dynamic proxy.. help me a lot!